Error 403 con Dio - Flutter Dio
quisiera solicitar una ayuda, estoy tratando de crear una mascota a través de una solicitu usando Dio a una api que hice en django, el tema es que me da el siguiente error y aun no descubro porqué "Se produjo una excepción.
_Exception (Exception: Error al registrar la mascota: DioException [bad response]: This exception was thrown because the response has a status code of 403 and RequestOptions.validateStatus was configured to throw for this status code.
The status code of 403 has the following meaning: "Client error - the request contains bad syntax or cannot be fulfilled"
Read more about status codes at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status
In order to resolve this exception you typically have either to verify and fix your request code or you have to fix the server code.
)"
les paso el codigo de mi solicitud
    import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
    import 'package:tfg_app/models/mascotas.dart';
    import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    // solicitud para registrar mascotas
    class MascotaService {
      Dio dio = Dio();

  Future<void> registrarMascota(Mascota mascota, BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      // Obtener el token del usuario
      String? token = await SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
        return prefs.getString('token');
      });
      print('Token obtenido: $token');

      // Crear los datos del formulario
      FormData formData = await mascota.toFormData();
      print('Datos del formulario: $formData');
      // Hacer la solicitud
      Response response = await dio.post(
        'https://tfg-admin.onrender.com/mascotas/registrar', // url de la api
        data: formData,
        options: Options(
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',  // Incluir el token en la cabecera
          },
        ),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // si el inicio de sesión es exitoso, redirigir a la página de mascotas_vistas
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/mascotas');
        
      } else {
        throw Exception('Error al registrar la mascota');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Error al registrar la mascota: $e');
    }
  }
}

el código de la clase Mascota
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'dart:io';

class Mascota {
  String nombre;
  String especie;
  String raza;
  String sexo;
  String edad;
  File? imagen;
  
  Mascota(this.nombre, this.especie, this.raza, this.sexo, this.edad, this.imagen);
  
  Future <FormData> toFormData() async {
    return FormData.fromMap({
      'nombre': nombre,
      'especie': especie,
      'raza': raza,
      'sexo': sexo,
      'edad': edad,
      'imagen': imagen == null ? null : await MultipartFile.fromFile(imagen!.path),
    });
  }
}

El código de la api a la que se realiza la peticion.
    # registrar mascota
    @api_view(['POST'])
    @permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])  # Requiere que el usuario esté autenticado
    def registrar_mascota(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            usuario = request.user  # El objeto User del usuario autenticado
            serializer = MascotaSerializer(data=request.data) # Se crea un serializador con los datos de la petición
            if serializer.is_valid():
                archivo_imagen = request.FILES.get('imagen') # Se obtiene la imagen de la petición
                if archivo_imagen:
                    nombre_archivo = f'mascotas/{uuid.uuid4()}.{archivo_imagen.name.split(".")[-1]}' # Se genera un nombre único para la imagen
                    imagen_url = storage.child(nombre_archivo).put(archivo_imagen)
                    serializer.save(usuario=usuario, imagen_url=imagen_url['downloadTokens']) # Se guarda la mascota en la base de datos
                    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)# Se responde con los datos de la mascota creada
                else:
                    return Response({'error': 'No se proporcionó ninguna imagen'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)# Se responde con un error si no se proporcionó ninguna imagen
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)# Se responde con los errores del serializador si no es válido

y el Serializer que utiliza la api
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Mascota

# Serializador para el modelo Mascota
class MascotaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    imagen = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Mascota
        fields = ['nombre', 'especie', 'raza', 'edad', 'sexo', 'usuario', 'imagen']

Desde ya agradezco mucho la ayuda, si hay algun error por mas que sea obvio por favor me dicen, soy muy nuevo en esta forma de trabajo.
